# Redirecting all URLS to my app

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have a need where I have to make all the URLs from chrome or any browser to open in my application. How can I do this in android?

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:path="/.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="/Android" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Currently I am using the above code in my project. This redirects all the links from other apps to my app. But not from Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. There is no requirement for a browser to necessarily pay attention to any other apps out there that might be interested in a URL. In particular, it seems that Chrome assumes that all `http`/`https` URLs are simply to be loaded as Web pages from the Internet. Other browsers may behave the same way.

Comment: Is it not possible even if I mention the android scheme as "http"?

Comment: @swetha: Again, if a Web browser wants to treat an HTTP URL as something that it will just handle itself, rather than see if there are any `ACTION_VIEW` activities for it, the browser is welcome to do so. The `http` URL `<intent-filter>` is for links showing up in *other sorts of apps*, such as a text messaging client, that might trigger either a browser or an app to appear.